# SEO Category and sub category

Tags: seo, google, wordpress

I have some issues with my SEO. The goal of the web site I am creating is to display all of my products by category and then by sub-category. My question is: if I display my products in archive category pages and in archive subcategory pages, will google see it duplicate content? Please excuse me for my English. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is same content available using two URLs? Yes. Then it is duplicate content.

Comment: This is not what I asked ! My question is for archieve page not single page, so of course there are differents URLs (one for my category page and one for my subcategory page) ! Please don't "marked as duplicate" when you don't really read my question !

Comment: I read your question and came up with the same thing as John. Can you reedit so that it is clearer?? Search engines do not know archive from spumoni- all URLs are just URLs and web all pages are just web pages. If you have two URLs that show the same page or nearly the same page, one or more will be marked as duplicate by the search engine.